# Apache2 Virtual Hosts Wordpress FTP Failed

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, apache-http-server, virtual-host

I'm trying to set up a hosting server where I can start putting up multiple sites.  I'm having problems installing a wordpress theme using FTP.
I've got a virtual host up, and it points `russellperformance.co` to `/vol/www/rpe/wordpress/`

I've got `vsftpd` installed, a user `ftprpe` set up and added to the `www-data` group.  My `/etc/group` file includes this on the www-data section `www-data:x:33:ftprpe`

When I point the install theme section to `russellperformance.co` and enter the ftp user info, I get a failed to connect?

I have no idea how to figure out what is going on?  `/var/log/vsftpd.log` is completely empty?

Anyone have any ideas on what is going on?